# iOS: How to ascertain the CPU type, e.g. A4 or A5, or instruction set architecture arm6 or arm7?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, arm

Does Apple provide an API that gives access to this information?

Does the ARM have an equivalent to the x86 CPUID instruction that I could use in an asm block?

Thanks.

Comment: I do not have a definite answer but from how insanely STRICT Apple is with their API, plus the history of banning developers for using third-party API or hidden API or non-public API (long story), I wouldn't even imagine these things being possible on an iPhone. Its a closed system, and a highly controlled and regulated one, pro and cons aside.

Comment: Yes the arm has many CPUID registers to cover the processor vendor version etc itself plus an array of them to cover features of the processor, instruction set stuff, coprocessors, cache features, etc

Answer (score 1):

Erica Sadun has written a number of useful queries.  I would begin checking out the uidevice extensions code and see if you can find what you are looking for there.

https://github.com/erica/uidevice-extension

Also, as Gapton says, keep in mind that some device queries will not get App Store approval, especially the unpublished ones, but a fair number of them are okay to use.

Answer (score 0):

I need CPU model info and instruction set. So I try to do it as simple as possible:

```
std::string GetCPUModel()
{
    // you can compare results with https://www.theiphonewiki.com/wiki/List_of_iPhones

    struct utsname systemInfo;
    uname(&systemInfo);

    std::string version(systemInfo.version);

    size_t cpuModelPos = version.find("RELEASE_");

    if (cpuModelPos != String::npos)
    {
        // for example: will return "ARM64_S8000" - for iPhone S6 plus
        return version.substr(cpuModelPos + strlen("RELEASE_"));
    }

    return {};
}
```